# Como salvar um array de chars em uma variavel?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou fazendo um programa de criptografia, começando inverter a *string* com o seguinte código:

```
namespace APS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string frase;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma frase: ");
            frase = Console.ReadLine();
            frase = frase.ToLower();
            frase = frase.Replace(" ","0");
            var chars = frase.ToCharArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", frase);
            Console.WriteLine("Character array: ");
            for (int i = frase.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
                Console.Write(chars[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Funciona e a *string* é invertida. Mas quando vou salvar `chars[i]` em uma variável, ou seja, salvar toda *string* invertida em uma variável da erro, fica assim:

```
using System;

namespace APS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string frase;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma frase: ");
            frase = Console.ReadLine();
            frase = frase.ToLower();
            frase = frase.Replace(" ","0");
            var chars = frase.ToCharArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", frase);
            Console.WriteLine("Character array: ");
            for (int i = frase.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
                VAR EXEMPLO = chars[i];
                //QUAL A FORMA CERTA DE SALVER TODA ESSA SEQUÊNCIA DE CARACTERES?
        }       
    }
}
```

Como faço para salvar e usar fora do laço de repetição `for`?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de escrever tudo em caixa alta?

Comment: Recomendo que leia [**este link**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489/28595).

Comment: Mas foi assim mesmo que escreveu? Isto é uma sintaxe errada mesmo, você conhece a sintaxe do C#?

Answer (score 1):

O código é confuso e ineficiente, para construir *strings* deve usar o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), sem ele a complexidade dele se torna proibitiva em grandes textos.

E se vai manipular cara caractere individualmente faça tudo o que precisa nele de uma vez. Quando manipula *strings* por inteiro cada vez está fazendo uma laço e está alocando memória que pode ser desnecessário, como este caso. Só porque não vê a complexidade escondida pelo método não significa que ela não está lá. Não use um método sequer sem saber o que ele faz. A maioria tem efeitos colaterais danosos para certas situações. Alguns são consideramos até legados.

Note que não está criando criptografia alguma com este código. Nem perto disto.

Até tem como tornar mais eficiente eliminando até a alocação do `StringBuilder`, mas não acho que seja tão importante, seria para o máximo de eficiência e fosse feito testes para determinar se com pensa mesmo.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("Digite uma frase: ");
        var frase = ReadLine();
        WriteLine($"Original string: {frase}");
        var invertida = new StringBuilder(frase.Length);
        foreach (var chr in frase) invertida.Append(char.ToLower(chr == ' ' ? '0' : chr));
        WriteLine($"Character array: {invertida}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LfUIWz). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLWEuA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Builder.cs).

Answer (score 0):

**I.** A variável exemplo estava sendo reescrita.

**II.** ela não é uma variável global e sim uma variável local, então ela só existe naquele contexto, se você tentar utilizar ela fora da estrutura *for* acusará erro exatamente por esse motivo.

**Código funcionando:**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var exemplo = "";
            string frase;
            Console.WriteLine("Digite uma frase: ");
            frase = Console.ReadLine();
            frase = frase.ToLower();
            frase = frase.Replace(" ","0");
            var chars = frase.ToCharArray();
            Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", frase);
            for (int i = frase.Length - 1; i > -1; i--){
                exemplo += chars[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Character array: " + exemplo);

    }
}
```

Comment: vlw mesmo. kkk tao simple de resolver obrigado

Comment: @ViniciusCaetano que bom cara kk, pode marcar a resposta como aceita então?

Comment: So mais uma duvida aqui:

Comment: como eu faco para pegar o indece de um array e nao o seu valor. Ex: char[] a = new char[]{'a','b','c'}; eu nao quero a[0] = a, eu quero pegar so o indece tipo se a qual seu indece no array

Comment: @ViniciusCaetano o recomendado seria você fazer outra pergunta ou editar essa sua perguntando sobre isso. ao lado das respostas tem duas setas, uma para cima e outra para baixo, abaixo da seta para baixo fica um símbolo de corrigido/checked que ao passar a seta do mouse por cima ela fica verde, é ali que marca a resposta como aceita. abs!